# Can't connect to Flask API running in VM from Host Maschine

Tags: python, flask, virtual-machine

I set up a Flask API in a Ubuntu Virtual Maschine (Virtual Box).
The VM is on bridged mode. Now i want to request data from the API from the Host System (Windows) and it always tells me that the connection is refused.
I tried switching to Host Only but if I try to run the VM with that it instantly crashes. I can ping the VM from Windows but can't get through to Port 5000.
I think its either a Virtual Box or a Flask issue.
Code of my API:

```
@app.route('/fnd/<text>', methods=['GET'])
def fnd(text):
    print(text)
    return jsonify(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000, Debug=False)
```

[Browser Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfJzb.png)

[Virtual Box Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arsix.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far to resolve the problem? What were the results?

Comment: I guess the problem is that port 5000 from Virtual Box wasn't exposed on your local machine. Also, you don't have a binding between 5000 internal port and 5000 external port.

Comment: @WBM I tried switching to Host Only  and to NAT but the VM instantly crashes when in Host Only Mode. I tried various settings within Flask wich did't worked either.